# What are the traits of a well made Cappuccino?

Tags: brewing-process, cappuccino

How can you check if a Cappuccino coffee was prepared correctly? What specific traits will a properly prepared Cappuccino display that poorly made Cappuccino's will not?

I've heard that when you it stands still upside down (with perfectly steamed milk and froth is insanely heavenly), then it's perfect. Is that true?

Comment: I voted to close because this is too opinion based, Cappuccino styles vary and what is perfect for one person is not perfect for others.

Comment: Changed 'perfect' to 'good', does it helps? Or there is simply no way to recognise good or bad Cappuccino?

Comment: I have made an edit I hope helps

Comment: For comparison see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36465/how-to-identify-a-good-espresso It's about espresso, but still a good example. You can write a list of fairly specific criteria, though there's still room for opinion ("bitter, but not too bitter") and perhaps some points are debateable or more a matter of tradition. If you think that sort of thing is valuable knowledge to have on the site, keep questions like this open!

Comment: @Jefromi - a good counterpoint. To me, there's more variability and "art" to cappuccino, as compared to a somewhat more precise science of an espresso (compare the Italian Espresso National Institute guidelines [transcribed at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso#Brewing_process)).  Hopefully PatrickSebastien will grace this question with a similarly excellent answer to the one you linked! I gave a stab below on preparation as pertains to being well-made.

Comment: A certain amount of subjectivity is okay; in cases like this, I think it's more important for the answers to try and remain objective than for the question to be edited. eg. don't answer saying "the coffee is perfect if it is made with a dark roast" which is very much an opinion answer "the cappuccino is perfect if the microfoam is [whatever foam should be like to define it as a cappuccino]"... I don't have a good example for cappuccino, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My take on this is to focus on the mechanics and preparation, which I think is an important part (though perhaps not *all*) of a cappuccino being properly made.

Fundamentally, a [cappuccino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappuccino#Preparation) consists of espresso and steamed milk (see distinction from a [latte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latte)). The [World Barista Championship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Barista_Championship) specifies the proper construction in their [beverage definitions (.PDF)](http://www.worldbaristachampionship.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2015-WBC-FINAL.pdf) in §2.2.2. It consists of a single-shot of espresso (25 mL / ~0.8 fl. oz.), textured (steamed) milk, and *at least* 1 cm of foam (other places suggest 2 cm). Total volume is 150-180 mL / 5-6 fl. oz.  To the extent that you subscribe to the WBC being a benchmark, the **components**, **volume**, and **amount of foam** define physical properties of a properly made cappuccino. It also states that the components should be in "harmonious balance."

The WBC states that aspects of the service are also crucial, such as

- **visual appearance**, such as that the beverage should fill the cup;
- **served with accoutrements**, such as "spoon, napkin and unflavoured water";
- **logistical aspects** of drinking, such as temperature and holding the cup.

Beyond that, there's a lot of variability that might lean closer to personal preference. Some other topics mentioned at WBC and Wikipedia include being "wet" (referring to the foam, versus "dry"), and "traditional" (solid central circle of white foam, versus having [latte art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latte_art)).

Other recipes for cappuccino at home vary greatly:

- [Folgers suggests](http://www.folgerscoffee.com/coffee-how-to/how-to-videos/cappuccino) to use equal parts of coffee (French press or drip), steamed milk, and foam. You'll get a rather different outcome from using coffee instead of espresso.
- [illy suggests](http://www.illy.com/wps/wcm/connect/en/coffee/how-prepare-cappuccino) quantities for a more traditional preparation, using espresso and steamed/foamed milk.